# Getting Input using KeyBindings

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, key-bindings

I have a program which I want to use keybindings:

```
// Imports..
public class Test{

JButton button = new JButton();

Test(){
//...
button.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "A");
button.getActionMap().put("Action", action);
//...
}
}
```

Now how do I make the button respond when it is clicked?

Is it like KeyListeners where I have an actionPerformed method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now how do I make the button respond when it is clicked?

from [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) is there only one way

```
button.doClick();
```

then this code line to invoke [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) or [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) added to the [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#jbutton)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it like KeyListeners where I have an actionPerformed method?

A `KeyListener` has no `actionPerformed` method!  The solution is to add an `ActionListener`, or as @mKorbel points out, create the button using an `Action`.